# Alterar o font-size pelo @font-face

Tags: html5, css3

É possível alterar o `font-size` de uma fonte dentro do `@font-face`?
Estou tentando o seguinte:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: kivetts;
    src: url(fonts/kivettsregular.otf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: DicksHandwriting;
    src: url(fonts/DicksHandwriting.otf);
    font-size:1.5em;
}

.menu-image-title {
    font-family: 'kivetts', DicksHandwriting
}
```

A primeira fonte não possuí o caractér Ó, então quero usar o Ó da segunda, no entanto a segunda fonte é menor que a primeira, por isso preciso aumentar ela.
Se souber de alguma outra forma de resolver este problema, por favor, indique um caminho.
Obrigado!

Comment: Você não poderia fazer assim: `<h4>P<span class="font_o" >ó</span></h4>` e so style `.font_o { font-size: 1.5em; }` ?

Comment: Infelizmente não, os textos serão dinâmicos, não tenho como inserir `<span></span>` em todos os "ó". Grato.

Comment: E como você faria para mudar de fonte nos "ó"?

Comment: Dessa forma: `font-family: 'kivetts', DicksHandwriting`. Veja em funcionamento: [http://108.179.252.83/~magnolia/] repare no menu, aquele "ó" é da segunda fonte, pois a primeira não tem esse carácter.

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente o @font-face só permite alterar os seguintes atributos da fonte: font-family, src, font-stretch (condensamento), font-style e font-weight.

Se for coisa pequena, talvez o font-weight pode resolver o teu problema.

Outra solução é adicionar um font-size padrão, como abaixo:

```
* {
  font-size: 1.5em; 
}
```

Comment: Boa explicação, só acho que mudar o `* {}`  não é um bom caminho, talvez seja melhor indicar isto `.menu-image-title {font-size: 1.5em; }`

Comment: Verdade, Guilherme. Se é só para esta classe, melhor usar direto nela.